# Rounding dates to first day of the month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, sql-server-2014

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I am working with a column from one of my tables, which list arrival dates.

It is in the following format:

```
ArrivalDate
2015-10-17 00:00:00.000
2015-12-03 00:00:00.000
```

I am writing a query that would pull data from the above table, including the ArrivalDate column. However, I will need to convert the dates so that they become the first day of their respective months.

In other words, my query should output the above example as follows:

```
2015-10-01 00:00:00.000
2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
```

I need this so that I can create a relationship with my Date Table in my PowerPivot model.

I've tried this syntax but it is not meeting my requirements:

```
CONVERT(CHAR(4),[ArrivalDate], 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), [ArrivalDate], 120) AS [MTH2]
```

Comment: Is that column actually a `datetime` field, or is it stored in some variation of `varchar`?

Comment: It's a datetime field.

Comment: In which case it does not have a "format". You're really asking about needing to do some arithmetic with dates to find the first of the month for a given date.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If, for example, it is 15th of given month then you subtract 14 and cast the result to date:

```
SELECT ArrivalDate
     , CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -DATEPART(DAY, ArrivalDate) + 1, ArrivalDate) AS DATE) AS FirstDay
FROM (VALUES
    (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
) AS t(ArrivalDate)
```

```
ArrivalDate             | FirstDay
2019-05-15 09:35:12.050 | 2019-05-01
```

But my favorite is [`EOMONTH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) which requires SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT ArrivalDate
     , DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(ArrivalDate, -1)) AS FirstDay
FROM (VALUES
    (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
) AS t(ArrivalDate)
```

```
ArrivalDate             | FirstDay
2019-05-15 09:35:52.657 | 2019-05-01
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed!

Comment: Perfect! Thank you sir!

Answer (score 13):

Use **[`FORMAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx)** to format your date.

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = '2015-10-17 00:00:00.000'

SELECT FORMAT(@date, 'yyyy-MM-01 HH:mm:ss.fff')
```

Or if you don't want time part:

```
SELECT FORMAT(@date, 'yyyy-MM-01 00:00:00.000')
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/377444)**</kbd>

Comment: Does the job! Highly appreciated.

Comment: With MySQL: `DATE_FORMAT(@date, '%Y-%m-01')`

Answer (score 11):

Beginning with SQL Server 2012, you can also use [`DATEFROMPARTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/hh213228.aspx):

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(ArrivalDate), MONTH(ArrivalDate), 1)
FROM   my_table
```

Answer (score 8):

Round date to first of the month:

```
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, DateColumn), 0)
```

Answer (score -3):

Or just simply use the ROUND function -

SELECT ROUND (TO_DATE ('27-OCT-00'),'YEAR')
   "New Year" FROM DUAL;

### New Year

01-JAN-01

Comment: For a SQL Server question this look kind of Oraclish